# How to call operator >> in derived class?

Tags: c++

How can I call the operator >> of the base class from derived class? In the derived class I want to read A and also B, but I do not know how to do it properly, thank you very much!

```
class Base {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Base &base) {
        input >> A;
    }
protected:
    int A;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Derived &derived) {
        // How can I call the operator >> from base class?
        input >> B;
    }
protected:
    int B;
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question but you're missing some return statements.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as `operator>>` is a friend function and not a member function, you need to change the implementation for base:

```
class Base {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Base &base) {
        input >> base.A;
    }
private:
    int A;
};
```

And for derived:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Derived &derived) {
        input >> static_cast<Base&>(derived);
        input >> derived.B;
    }
private:
    int B;
};
```

also note, that friendship is not inherited. That is, you can not do

```
input >> static_cast<Base&>(derived).A
```

as `operator>>(istream& input, Derived &derived)` is not a friend of `Base`.

Also note, that the way you use inheritance is problematic and confusing, as you will get different behavior if you use a base reference or not. Even if you rewrote it to use virtual functions, functions using base would not know what to expect (how much of the stream it will eat).
With the you have, there's confusion regarding what the expected behavior is for this:

```
Base b;
Derived d1;    
Base& b1 = d1;

{
  std::string_steam ss ; 
  ss << "1 2";
  ss >> b; // will set A to 1 and leave 2 in the stream
}
{
  std::string_steam ss ; 
  ss << "1 2";
  ss >> d1; // will set A to 1 and B to 2
}
{
  std::string_steam ss ; 
  ss << "1 2";
  ss >> b1; // will set A to 1 and leave 2 in stream 
}
```

It's hard for a user (a function taking base reference) to know how to use such object.

Also read up on [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: It would be must simpler to use a virtual function that derived classes override, and have a single extractor for the base class that calls the function internally. That way you don't have to have a friend for each class.

Comment: Also, C++ doesn't support Open Multi Method. In a polymorphic situation that won't work as one might expect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define some kind of `read` virtual function as follow if you want to use it in a polymorphic situation:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual istream& read(istream& in) {
        return in >> A;
    }
// private: // for demo
    int A = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    virtual istream& read(istream& in) {
        Base::read(in);
        return in >> B;
    }
//private: // for demo
    int B = 0;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Base &base) {
    return base.read(input);
}
```

Note that in this piece of code operator `>>` is not a friend of anybody.

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/z3EKfs)

With input `1 2`, the following program works as expected.

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base& b = d;

    cout << d.B << " - " << d.A << endl; // 0 - 0

    cin >> b; 

    cout << d.B << " - " << d.A << endl; // 1 - 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's still breaking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle . Only if you know what the reference b is can you know how much of the stream it will eat, which may be quite unexpected.

Comment: @JohanLundberg of which specific LSP are you talking?

Comment: You can always say that in this case this is the intention, but I'm thinking about the post condition: Having a derived class eat a different amount (and using it differently) from a stream is suspicious.

Comment: That's what the article also refer to by "if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (e.g., correctness)." And the *desirable* properties or *correctness* of the program only depend on the programmer's definition.

Comment: Well. Principles like these are there to help you know when you enter murky waters. You can always convince yourself they don't apply to your case. Do you argue this is good code?

Comment: It depends on what the OP what to achieve and the context. That's why I said "you *might* want".